# Samsung S4 Mini (GT-I9195) TWRP recovery fails

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, twrp, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini (GT-I9195) and successfully installed CyanogenMod 13 with the CM 13 Recovery on it. Now I am stuck with the installation of [GApps](http://opengapps.org/?api=6.0&variant=nano) by means of TWRP.

I have tried to follow [this](https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxys4miniuscellular.html) tutorial to install TWRP (3.0.1 or 2.8.7):

1. App Install Method: it tells me that something went wrong and it does not boot the recovery, indeed. What seems wired to me is that when I have to choose an image it shows me the device code **serranolteusc** and **serranoveltexx** for my S4 Mini rather than **serranoltexx**, like on the website of CM 13. Is this normal?

   (I even tried Flashify instead of the TWRP manager, but it did not function!)
2. Since I am on Linux and have no Windows, I cannot use the Odin method. But I tried Heimdall via `heimdall flash --RECOVERY twrp.img --no-reboot` to no avail.
3. I tried the dd Install Method via `dd if=/sdcard/twrp.img of=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/recovery`, but it still does not boot into recovery mode. Is it possible that there is an issue with the path in `of=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/recovery`?

Is it possible that there is no TWRP for **serranoltexx** available?

Comment: I'm far from being familiar with Samsung devices, but speaking about Odin and Linux: Have you tried [JOdin3](http://www.xda-developers.com/meet-jodin3-a-web-tool-that-flashes-your-samsung-device/)? That's a web-based Odin variant and should work on non-Windows systems. Could be helpful in your case – and finally answer my curiosity on whether it works on Linux (I can't test that without a Samsung device ;)

Comment: After flashing the recovery using `dd`, what did you immediately do? How did you reboot into recovery mode later?

Comment: @ Firelord, I pressed **Vol Up**, **Power**, and **Home**, only to find out that the CM 13 recovery was still installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ever in doubt about partition paths (and said device is supported by CyanogenMod or Lineage OS), you can check this from their sources. But to your question at hand, looking at TWRP device trees, you need to use "serranolteusc" as "serranoveltexx" is meant for the newer 64-bit variant (why name them the same is beyond me). Using the image for "serranolteusc" with the Heimdall or terminal and `dd` command should be enough to get TWRP installed.

If that doesn't work, maybe provide a logcat of when you try to `dd` and see if it complains about anything specific.

Answer (score -1):

I rooted my serranoltexx (s4 Mini with LTE) using Kingroot and flashed TWRP using TWRP-App.